# Find the distribution ,when parameter is random

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be the number of coin tosses until heads is obtained. Suppose that the probability of heads is unknown in the sense that we consider it to be
a random variable $Y \in U(0, 1)$.

$(a)$ Find the distribution of $X$

this is what i have come to:

$X  \mid Y = y \enspace \in Geo(y)$

The unconditional distribution can be calculated as:  $\mathbb{P}(X = k) = \int_{0}^{1}  \mathbb{P}(X = k, Y = y )  dy =  \int_{0}^{1}  \mathbb{P}(X = k \mid Y = y ) f_Y(y)  dy =
  \int_{0}^{1} (1-y)^{k}y^1 \cdot 1 dy =  \frac{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma( k + 3) } \int_{0}^{1}  \frac{\Gamma( k + 3) }{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(k+1)}(1-y)^{k+1-1}y^{2 -1 } \cdot 1 dy =  \frac{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma( k + 3) }  = 1/(k+2)(k+1)$

where i have used the beta density  ,which is given by: $f(x) = \frac{\Gamma(r+s)}{\Gamma(r)\Gamma(s)} x^{r-1}(1-x)^{s-1}$ , $\beta(r,s), r,s > 0$

However the answer should be $1/k(k+1)$, so where did i go wrong?

Comment: Why did you introduce the gamma functions?

Comment: sorry beta density, i changed it

Comment: If $X$ counts the number of coin tosses *until* a head is obtained, you computed right $\mathbb{P}(X=k+1)$.

Comment: @Batman because $\int_{0}^{1}  \frac{\Gamma( k + 3) }{\Gamma(2)\Gamma(k+1)}(1-y)^{k+1-1}y^{2 -1 } \cdot 1 dy = 1$

Comment: $P\left\{ X=k\mid Y=y\right\} =\left(1-y\right)^{k-1}y$

Comment: @drhab Geometric distribution is $Geo(p)$: $p(k) =p^kq$  ,$k=1,2,,$  and $q = 1-p$

Comment: Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution. There are two candidates. Wich one should be applied here?

Comment: Let $X$ be the number of coin tosses until heads is obtained

Comment: It has been pointed out already, but the probability that there are $k$ trials until the first success is $(1-y)^{k-1}y$. And the integration is simple, let $u=1-y$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas "Let X be the number of coin tosses until heads is obtained" , i should interpret this as "including" the toss that made a head. not as counting the number of failures

Comment: There are in fact two versions of the geometric distribution, one counts just the number of failures. But in what I wrote above, I took the number of trials interpretation that you want to use. The number of **trials** is $k$ precisely if there are $k-1$ failures followed by a success. The probability of this is $(1-y)^{k-1}y$.

Answer (score 2):

The criteria "tosses until a head" means we are using the **geometric distribution** rather than the **shifted geometric distribution** (which would count "tails before a head").   (Misfortunately the shifted geometric distribution is called just "the geometric distribution" in some texts.   This is a leading cause of confusion.   It is always best to be clear on just which you are using, and whyfor.)

$$\begin{align}
(X\mid Y) \sim {\cal Geo}(Y) &\iff \Pr(X=k\mid Y=y) = (1-y)^{k-1} y, \forall k\in \{1,2,\ldots \} 
\\[1ex] Y \sim {\cal U}[0,1] & \iff f_Y(y) = 1
\\[2ex]
\Pr(X=k) 
& = \int_0^1 \Pr(X=k \mid Y=y) f_Y(y)\operatorname{d}y 
\\ &= \int_0^1 \left((1-y)^{(k-1)}y\right) \cdot 1\operatorname{d}y
\\ & = \left[-\frac{(1-y)^k}{k} y\right]_{y=0}^{y=1} + \int_0^1 \frac{(1-y)^k}{k}\operatorname{d}y
\\ & = 0 + \left[-\frac{(1-y)^{k+1}}{k(k+1)} \right]_{y=0}^{y=1}
\\[1ex] \therefore \Pr(X=k) & = \frac{1}{k(k+1)} 
\end{align}$$

---

For completion: if we *had* been counting $X_s$ the number of tails *before* a head occurs — thus using a shifted geometric distribution — then:

$$X_s\mid Y \sim {\cal Geo}_s(y) \iff \Pr(X_s=k\mid Y=y) = (1-y)^k y, k\in\{{\bf 0},1,2,\ldots\} \\ \therefore \Pr(X_s=k) = \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$